# What are the differences between TLS and PGAS?

Tags: multithreading, memory, parallel-processing

What are the key differences between [thread-local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (TLS) and [partitioned global address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitioned_global_address_space) (PGAS)? What are the implications of languages or programs using one or the other?

Comment: These are very different concepts. Can you look up the definitions of each and try to pose a more specific question?

Comment: @Jeff I asked because I had already done that (see links) and wasn't sure of the differences. My thought was that PGAS is like TLS (which I think I understand). TLS keeps memory local to each thread, but there are usually mechanisms to deal with global/shared variables. PGAS has a global address space, but partitions it in a way that seems a lot like TLS. The part of the wikipedia explanation of PGAS I don't understand is where it talks about locality of reference and affinity of the shared memory space.

Comment: Ok, there is a superficial similarity here, but in practice PGAS "threads" are actually OS processes.  PGAS also supports distributed memory. I'll try to write a proper answer when I get near a proper keyboard.

Comment: @Jeff Cool, I look forward to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are at least superficially similar approaches, but the practical implications are quite different.

TLS is how one specifies that automatic variables (i.e. data on the stack) are associated with operating system (OS) threads (e.g. POSIX threads) and not the entire OS process.

Below is an example of TLS in OpenMP.  I am using OpenMP because C11 threads are not supported by GCC or Clang yet.  The equivalent syntax in C11 (C++11) is `_Thread_local` (`thread_local`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int p;
#pragma omp threadprivate(p)
int s;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("%d: %p %p\n", omp_get_thread_num(), &p, &s );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, the output of this code is:

```
> OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./tls
1: 0x7fdbb1404ea8 0x1004a5060
2: 0x7fdbb1500c08 0x1004a5060
3: 0x7fdbb1500c18 0x1004a5060
4: 0x7fdbb1500c28 0x1004a5060
5: 0x7fdbb1500c38 0x1004a5060
6: 0x7fdbb1500c48 0x1004a5060
0: 0x7fdbb1500c58 0x1004a5060
7: 0x7fdbb1500c68 0x1004a5060
```

As you can see here, the TLS data addresses are different on every thread, whereas the address of the global without TLS is the same for all threads.

In PGAS, one usually assumes a *distributed memory* system.  Data is allocated privately to every thread (here a thread may be an OS thread, OS process, or something else) *by default*.  Shared data can be allocated as necessary.

Below is a SHMEM program.  In this program, the `sheap` data is a pointer in every PE (processing element, which is usually an OS process) that can be accessed by any other PE using function calls like `shmem_getmem` and `shmem_putmem`.

```
#include <shmem.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    start_pes(0);
    int mype = my_pe();
    int npes = num_pes();

    int n = ( argc>1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000);
    int * sheap = shmalloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (sheap==NULL) exit(1);
    printf("PE %d: sheap base = %p\n", mype, sheap);
    shfree(sheap);

    return 0;
}
```

In a PGAS language like UPC, one can use load-store syntax, but the compiler will translate these to network communication function calls if the data lives in a remote location (remote means a different node in a distribute memory system).

The fundamental difference between TLS and PGAS is that TLS works in a threaded context where data is *shared by default* and TLS is used to privatize it, whereas in PGAS all data is *private by default*, and shared data can allocated upon request.

Does this help?  I know that C++11 and UPC examples would be more helpful than OpenMP and SHMEM, but it was easier to write the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the time writing this. Very helpful.